# Replace with uuid(or random number)

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, replace

I want to replace content in json with a unique number, say uuid.
My json is

```
let response =   
{
  "data": {
    "address": [
      {
        "city": "wildcard"
      },
      {
        "city": "wildcard"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to replace wildcard with unique numbers.

My code is

```
response = response.replace(new RegExp('wildcard','g'), uuid.v4());
```

its replacing all the wildcard in the json with a single UUID, I want each wildcard to be replaced with a unique uuid.v4().

Basically I need help to call uuid.v4() each time while replacing the wildcard ?

Comment: The code you have here would result in an error when you tried to call `replace`. Please share actual code you've tested.

Comment: If `response` is actually a string, try `response = response.replace(new RegExp('wildcard', 'g'), uuid.v4);`

Comment: why dont you write Math.random() instead of uuid.v4()?

Comment: @ShrikanthBuds [*"Math.random() does not provide cryptographically secure random numbers"*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random).

Comment: Is `response` actually a string or object?

Comment: Its a string (after converting response to string)

Answer (score 1):

```
response = response.replace(new RegExp('@uuid','g'),() => uuid.v4());
```

worked for me. 
Reason: Replacing that with a function which returns uuid makes sure a unique id is returned every time that function is called.

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Comment: This "makes sure a unique id is returned every time that function is called" is beautiful @Abhijeet